# C++ quickfix FieldMap group information access

Tags: c++, tags, quickfix

I am writing a generic FIX engine based on quickfix C++ lib. Assume the engine will connect to a destination which use version 4.4. According to the version std, I'll know what those groups I should check. The destination may add its custom group say XGrp. FieldMap has g_begin()/g_end().

Question 1:

would m_groups contains XGrp data?

Question 2:
Now assume my engine does not know XGrp's tags. by accessing begin()/end(), is there anyway I can know a tag is a group tag? So starting from here I can access m_groups to get all  XGrp data?

of cource my code can keep all those processed std tags so to decide whether a tag is a custom one.

Question 3:

How to know whether there is 2nd level grp YGrp inside XGrp and How to access YGrp?

Question 4:
will all tags in begin()/end() appear in g_begin()/g_end()?